# Touch detection doesn't work on simulator for iOS 9

Tags: sprite-kit, ios-simulator, swift2, ios9, touchesbegan

I've updated Xcode to Xcode 7. Then my Swift project to Swift 2. At last I removed removed all warnings.

First scene display few `SKLabel` and few `SKSpriteNode`.

Using iOS Simulator, touch detection doesn't work under iOS 9 but is ok on iOS 8. A breakpoint put on`touchesBegan`method show this method is not called.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

  // Breakpoint is set here
}
```

### EDIT

Removing these messages does not solve anything.

Console display following warning 4 times, on iOS 9 only:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7ba430f0 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

Comment: Disabling Game Center capabilities remove these messages : on Project, select the *Desired target* and go to *Capabilities*. But touch detection still not work.

Comment: I believe the method signature changed for touchesBegan in iOS 9

Comment: @BenKane You're right and code have been modified according to this change. So this is not the origin of the problem...

Comment: Furthermore, I've noticed LaunchImage does not display in iOS 9 too...

Comment: You say that but haven't provided any code, so we don't know of it's actually true. Can you provide some code for context?

Comment: Question updated to add code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, problem solved!

On StoryBoard, `userInteractionEnabled` property on the main `View`of the initial view controller was set to "NO". Changed it to "YES" solve the problem.

This is weird because everything worked fine on iOS 8.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem on the simulator running iOS 9.0, and the issue turned out to be the language settings. I am posting my findings, so it can help anyone running into the same problem.

The simulator stops detecting touches if the region is set to India and Language to "English - India". To resolve the issue I reset the simulator and only changed the region to India, as my app functionality depends on the region. On retaining the language to "English - USA" the problem is not seen.

I am not sure what other language or region/language combinations can cause this issue. Hope this helps someone.